# How to ensure text wrapping in LaTex table

Tags: latex, word-wrap

When I am using below code for table in LaTex from second column onwards the table columns are not sticking to cell width given here. The table is exceeding page width as columns are getting expanded. How to resolve this issue.

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}
\smartqed
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Comparison of Block confirmation rate}
\label{tab:4} 
\begin{tabular}{p{1in} l p{2in} l p{2in} l p{2n} l p{2n}}
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
No of Organizations participating in Blockchain network [Column 1] & Available Bandwidth in Mbps for each node [10Mbps*1/2n(n-1)] [Column 2] 
 & No of messages of size 560bytes from each node with available bandwidth [Column 3] & No of Blocks (NBCT) (Number of nodes * number of message from column 3)  [Column 4] & Blocks (OBCT) [Column 5] \\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: can you make a compilable [mre]?

Comment: Pl see the example below

Answer (score 1):

Several problems:

- your table has 5 columns, yet you specify 9 columns, every second one left aligned without linebreaks.
- `2n` is not a valid unit for the width of a column, I suspect you mean `2in`?
- the document class you choose has a very narrow text width. Even after fixing all the problems above, there is not enough available space to fit 5 columns of 2 in each besides each other. Even with only 1 in, the table will still stick into the margin. Either choose another document layout or rethink the layout of the table.
- you might want to look into packages like `siunitx` to correctly typeset units and values ....

---

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}
\smartqed
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Comparison of Block confirmation rate}
\label{tab:4} 
\begin{tabular}{p{1in} p{1in} p{1in} p{1in} p{1in}}
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
No of Organizations participating in Blockchain network [Column 1] 
& Available Bandwidth in Mbps for each node [10Mbps*1/2n(n-1)] [Column 2] 
& No of messages of size 560bytes from each node with available bandwidth [Column 3] 
& No of Blocks (NBCT) (Number of nodes * number of message from column 3)  [Column 4] 
& Blocks (OBCT) [Column 5] \\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```